not to be able to see launcher and top menu bar in aws Amazon SageMaker
my system is Mac. I am new to amazon aws sagemaker. I just open an new personal aws account and then I searched for Amazon SageMaker Studio and then created a new user profile as executor and a new domain and then I clicked on open studio but I can not see launcher button to use system terminal and also can not see the top menu bar that has file, kernel and other options. I appreciate if anyone has any idea that I did by mistake in the scenario to open sagemaker studio so now I am unable to see these options.
enter image description here
I expected to see launcher option and the top menu bar such as File and Kernel options ...

From your image, the sagemaker studio domain is the "new studio" and all the things you want to access are either accessible through the clasic studio - which you can open by clicking the icon "Studio Classic", through code editor space or jupyterlab space.
You can find more info on the new UI and Studio in here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-updated.html
